# How to access localstorage on another window in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, session-storage

I am working with users.php page, so whenever I click on a link view_details.php infront of every user name:

1) It will create localstorage with that userid, and for every one second  localstorage will be check for that user id(whether it is empty or not ) and later open new window view_details.php

2) After  changes done in view_details.php I will update in table and clear localstorage from this window(view details.php).

3) As setinterval function is running in parent window(user.php) but when we clear this from view_details.php now parent window should show some alert that local storage is cleared for that user

but I am unable to access localstorage in view_details.php which was created in user.php

```
user.php

<script>
 $("body").on('click', '.view_user_details', function () {

 var user_id= $(this).attr("data-id");
 window.localStorage.setItem(user_key, user_id);  // localstorage is created here with user id      
 check_user_status();   // function called to check localstorage is cleared or not 

 //open view_details.php in new window 
          }
            function check_user_status() {
              setInterval(function () {

                if (localStorage.length > 0) {
                   console.log('user value:' + window.localStorage.getItem('user_key'));
                } else {
                    console.log('local storage clear');
                }
            }, 3000);
        }
    </script>
```

script for view details.php

```
<script>
     $(".save_details").click(function () {
       localStorage.clear();
        window.close();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: yes I tried that also but it didn't work for me

Comment: Forgive me I didn't understand your issue in the first place. Local storage is domain-wide so as long as you're clearing it, no matter the window in which you are doing it, it will clear the local storage for the whole domain
See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: _t's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: instead of pollying localStorage, you can use the `storage` event that will be fired when there is change in the localstorage.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

Comment: great idea to go with storage event .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap key with quote.

```
window.localStorage.setItem(user_key, user_id);
```

to

```
window.localStorage.setItem('user_key', user_id);
```